# Installing foren6 tool in ubuntu

Tags: linux

I would like to install **foren6** tool in ubuntu. But when I used the `make` command I get the following  error :

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):   Could not find
>   module FindLIBUSB.cmake or a configuration file for package   LIBUSB.
>
> Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindLIBUSB.cmake or set LIBUSB_DIR
>   to the   directory containing a CMake configuration file for LIBUSB. 
>   The file will   have one of the following names:
>
> ```
> LIBUSBConfig.cmake
> libusb-config.cmake
> ```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these commands in order?

```
$git clone https://github.com/cetic/foren6.git

$cd foren6

$make

$sudo make install
```

Comment: yes id but during that i am getting error at cd foren6 and then make gettiing error